# Flutter: FutureBuilder How can I load a future that receives arguments?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with a FutureBuider and I don't know how I can load a Future that receives an argument. I get an error, the future is in an external file 'provider.dart', I attach an image of the error:

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
> Try adding the missing arguments.dart(not_enough_positional_arguments)

[image: Image Error]

To explain myself better I have to mention the structure of the application:

- HomePage: in it you select an image that will be sent to a 'provider.dart' file.
- PhotoPage:  On this page, a value obtained from the Provider.dart file is obtained through a FutureBuilder, as shown in the image above.

```
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: fotoProvider.uploadImageCloudinary(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error.toString()}'),
                );
              }
              
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              
              return Center(
                // I WOULD LIKE TO PRESENT THE RESULTS OF THE SECOND FUTURE HERE
                child: Text(snapshot.data),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

- Provider.dart: There are two Future's:

1 Future: It receives the image from the home and processes it sending it to the Cloudinary API, I get the url generated by Cloudinary to be sent to the second Future.

```
Future<String> uploadImageCloudinary(File imagen) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://api.cloudinary.com/...');
 
    final mimeType = mime(imagen.path).split('/'); // Image/jpeg
    final imageUploadRequest = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
 
    final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'file',
      imagen.path,
      contentType: MediaType(mimeType[0], mimeType[1]),
    );
 
    imageUploadRequest.files.add(file);
 
    // execute request
    final streamResponse = await imageUploadRequest.send();
    final resp = await http.Response.fromStream(streamResponse);
 
    if (resp.statusCode != 200 && resp.statusCode != 201) {
      print('Something went wrong');
      print(resp.body); // Error
      return null;
    }
 
    dynamic respData = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(respData);
 
    urlGenCloudinary = respData['secure_url'];

    // Shipment to the second future
    return await requestSecondAPI(urlGenCloudinary);
  }
```

2 Future: It receives the url and sends it to another API, this one processes it and generates a String that is the data that I want to be sent to FutureBuilder in FotoPage.

```
 Future requestSecondAPI(String url) async {
    final String apiUrl =
        "https://api...";
 
    final res = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Key "
      },
      
      body: jsonEncode({
        "inputs": [
          {
            "data": {
              "image": {'url': url}
            }
          }
        ],
        "model": {
          "output_info": {
            "output_config": {"max_concepts": 40, "min_value": 0.8}
          }
        }
      }),
    );
 
    final resReqRes = reqResRespuestaFromJson(res.body);
 
    String resultado = resReqRes.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].id;
    return resultado;
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

I tried to place the second Future in the FutureBuilder and I get the following errors:

[image: General image of the errors]

1. In FutureBuilder:
   "Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. "

[image: Image Error 1]

2. In the future within the FutureBuilder:
   "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
   Try adding the missing arguments."

[image: Image Error 2]

3. In the builder:
   "The argument type 'Center Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot)' "

[image: Image Error 3]

Comment: It;s obvious you need to pass arguments `String Url` and `File image` in both cases why this is even a question.

Comment: add  return type as `String`  in `Future<String> requestSecondAPI(String url) async {`

Comment: Bawantha: I know very well that I have to send arguments, but I send those arguments before from the HomePage not from the futureBuilder. I don't know if that's what you mean.

Comment: If you send them from HomePage you could say  `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('yourRoute', arguments: [variable1,variable2]);` Then, on your futurebuilder page you could say `variable1 = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments[0].` Just change your Navigator.of according to your needs. Take a look here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: This does not seem to be about the `FutureBuilder` class or Futures at all. Maybe you can focus on your actual question, with a simpler example. Like how to transfer the value of an int from one screen to another.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I did more research and I think StreamBuilder is more to my needs. I just posted a question, could you please review it?